# Why is removing tags from the title suggested so often?

Tags: discussion, edits, title

I noticed that a common type of edit is to remove words from the title that are in the tags list. Like "How do you do this and that in AngularJS" -- the "AngularJS" part gets removed.

I don't really get why this is good. The main tag usually is worth the place in the title since the question most likely revolves around that topic. Most of us are usually subscribed to many tags, so by default I see a lot of questions. Why is it better for me to only see "How to do this and that" -- and have to double check the tags if I really want to answer it?

Google will have less relevancy on the hit as well - albeit the person who performs the search will most likely include the main tag in the query...

Comment: Tags are there specifically for classifying the question into topics. Redundantly including it in the title is noise and wasted space you could use for a more informative question. I see no benefit in seeing 20 questions on the main page that have "in JavaScript" in the subject lines, and lots of reasons *not* to have that replicated 20 times. Use the tag system to identify questions you want to read/see/answer.

Comment: Well noted, Peter - I find it much easier to scan hundreds of questions that actually tell me the context in the title.

Comment: Note: the most popular tag is automatically prepended to the question title when displayed so it's useless to add it manually.

Comment: @Bakuriu I don't see that when I click on the questions list at all...?

Comment: Having the language or framework in your title can be a sign that the title doesn't actually cover the question well.

Comment: In the specific example you provided, I would say that AngularJS could stay. What should be change is a title like "How to properly use transform/translate CSS3".

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier I think that Bakuriu means in the Window title.  E.g., the window (or tab) title of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430466/jpype-class-not-found id "java - JPype class not found"

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor ah yes I see - He just doesn't have enough tabs open. I would have to close 15 to see that. Thx for solving that. I still agree with Peter though - the list is much easier to read with tags in title.

Comment: When I remove tags, I add the following: "I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not"."

Comment: Not commenting on official policy, just personal preference.  I am sympathetic with this title because when I edit, and in particular when I review, I ask does this edit make a non-trivial improvement in the post?  As a default, I generally side with the original poster and leave the post alone.  To remove tags from titles seems at the level of nit-picking.  As one of many reasons to edit a single post though, I can see this as sufficiently motivated.  Actually, I treat "Thanks" much the same.  I won't edit just because of it, but as part of a larger edit I see a benefit to get rid of it.

Comment: @Bakuriu The main tag is NOT prepended in google results so it's actually VITAL to have it there if you want to confirm that the result is even about what you searched for before you click it. So many comments and answers here talk about removing tagS but the question is about having a single main tag only in the title.

Comment: @Hasen 0) This is a 2014 discussion, the UI has changed since then, 0.1) I *never* said that the tag is added on the google results, it was shown in the SO result page 1) who cares about google? There is a search in SO... 2) StackOverflow clearly shows the tags right below the title on the search results so having a tag *in* the title is just noise. If you want to search using google just add the "tag" you'd like to search for in your query in google.

Comment: @Bakuriu "who cares about google?" I'm guessing that's a joke but if it is it doesn't help your argument much. Obviously, and I really do mean blatantly obviously, most everyone is gonna search in google and then end up at SO. If you want to search in google, then obviously you'll have the tag in your search query, but you also need to SEE that tag in the google results - again BLATANTLY obviously. If you search for something about C# you don't want to end up on a result about Java...or at least you should know before clicking, hence that tag name should be in the search result title..

Comment: Potential cross-site dupe on meta.SE: [Titles should be stand-alone summaries of questions *without* depending on tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180100)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Here's the main point:

### Titles should be sentences in ordinary English.

I'm a committed tag remover, and where I edit a title I modify it according to this policy. Thus, this current question:

> Cloud Storage Public URL - GAE

should be:

> CSS file not available in cloud storage public URL in GAE

That reads better because it is more descriptive of the actual problem, and furthermore it doesn't do any of this stuff:

- Here is a title [tag] [tag]
- Another title (tag, tag)
- Third title | tag

Urgh! Those are trying to replicate the tag system pointlessly, and could do with an edit (I probably would not edit those on their own, but in general someone who tags in this way will have other problems as well, such as txtspk, spelling issues, all-lower-case, lack of paragraphing etc).

However, your example is not tagged, in my view:

> How do you do this and that in AngularJS?

I would therefore leave that alone, since it is plain English and, as you say, the AngularJS adds context without putting ugly bar/bracket/dash/colon hacks in the text.

Comment: Given your belief that **Titles should be sentences in ordinary English** it's a shame that *CSS file not available in cloud storage public URL in GAE* is not such a sentence; it lacks a verb.

Comment: @High: I wouldn't say it's shameful, no - that sort of exaggeration is an abuse of language in itself! A sense of perspective is called for there, but nevertheless you are welcome to edit my post.

Comment: @Fattie: if you have a different answer to this, please either upvote another one that reflects your view, or write a new answer. Remember that comments here are not to exercise a vendetta - they are, at least on this page, an attempt to decide policy. Rightly or wrongly, my answer appears to be (at least _de facto_) policy, but I am happy for that to change if the community can be persuaded of a new position.

Comment: I'm more than happy to delete those comments if they seem "vendetta oriented" (?)  (Should the 'Given..." comment also be deleted?"  The comment factually pointed out that the answer asserts "don't use tags in headlines" and then confusingly gives an example with a tag in a headline (which is, anyway, poorly written).  In terms of "policy", as stated, simplistic "rules" like this can lead to time-wasting edits.

Answer (score 21):

**[Removing tags from titles is often NOT desirable.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180100/titles-should-be-stand-alone-summaries-of-questions-without-depending-on-tags)**

The very short version is this:

**Titles should be stand-alone summaries of questions *without* depending on tags.**

- Tags SHOULD be included in titles if a reader *who never sees the tags,* but might be interested in the question, will need them to know if they care to read the question.
- Tags need NOT be included in cases where anyone who'd care about the question wouldn't need them.  (Like in cases where the syntax in the title is commonly used in only one language, etc.)

Comment: Really?  We have a long history of removing tags from questions (especially at the beginning of the title), and the SE software already puts the most popular tag at the beginning the title anyway for Google search purposes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, you're right about Google, but SEO is usually the red herring in these discussions - users should be able to scan the "headlines" on the page and get a sense of which might be interesting without depending on the tags. Don't get me wrong, they should NOT be jammed in (and can be removed) when they're not needed for the title to convey the key info, but if the tag removal means you can envision 4 questions with the same title that all relate to different languages, we were better off with it in.

Comment: Fair enough.  We don't generally remove the tags when they're made a natural part of the question phrase... We remove them when they're simply tacked onto the beginning or end.

Comment: One problem with no tags is the "Hot Network Questions" that make absolutely no sense with the context from the tag.

Comment: *Some people* might not remove tags that are part of the natural wording of the title, but unfortunately such counterproductive changes do show up in the edit queue with the claim that tags should not be duplicated in the title at all, and get approved.

Comment: You know why this happens? It's because people conflate "tags" with "keywords" and think they absolutely *must be eradicated from prose* for that reason. Soon we're going to have users editing keywords out of *post bodies* just because "it's already in the tags".

Comment: @AShelly but... but... is awesome when the question comes from [gaming.se]

Comment: @Robert Harvey Google certainly doesn't include the tag in the title in it's results, maybe it did when you posted your comment but it doesn't anymore. I just did a few searched to check. It's vital to include the tag like "C#" in the title so a user searching in google will know that the result is actually about what he searched for before clicking, because often it won't be.

Comment: @Hasen: In general, title to post mapping isn't that great to begin with.  It would be nice if folks wrote good titles; that would provide much better mileage than worrying about tags in titles.

Comment: @Robert Harvey No idea what "title to post mapping" is, all we're talking about is writing the word 'C#' in a title of a question that is about C#....I think you're just trying to make things way more complex than they need to be. Nobody is talking about tagS but rather the single most vital tag only, in my example that would be C#, so that you know, people actually know what they're clicking on in google is even about before they click on it.... The way people go on about it it's like if I write 'C#' in my title, ten thousand babies die somewhere..

Comment: @Hasen: Title to Post mapping is exactly what you're describing: *the title matches the post,* which seldom happens, tags in titles notwithstanding.  It seems more complicated than you think it is because it is.

Answer (score 15):

The tags are shown on the question list, so if you want to know which tags apply, the information is already there, it's not adding any value to redundantly state it in the question.

If you have tags that you don't want to answer in your question list, then you might consider removing them from your favorites, or adding them to your ignored list.

The main tag is automatically injected into the HTML title of every page, just not the URL representing the title, so it gets all of that great Google Juice without you sticking the tag in the title.

Comment: Back to my example the question in fact is not "how to this and that".. The question positively is that "how to this and that IN ANGULARJS"

Comment: Letting me to decide if I can help or not - faster: it has value.

Comment: @PeterAronZentai How can you do anything any faster?  The same information is just a couple of pixels away.

Comment: I usually read 4-5 lines of text in the same time (parallel reading)... If I have to fiddle with tags - that slows me down and gets me off the flow from helping other ppl.

Comment: Without kidding: your brain definitely receives the bigger text faster - since the focus is on the bigger things. simple usability

Comment: @PeterAronZentai Then you can create your own client site script for the site to increase the size of tags for yourself, if it helps you.

Comment: And still, the question is not "how to do this and that". A more concrete example so you get it: "How to scroll the window" vs "How to scroll the window with AngularJS". The meaning gets ruined.

Comment: @PeterAronZentai The meaning isn't really ruined there, but in the event that it is, then it would be one of the exceptional cases that would either require a bit more of a re-write, or that would need to be left alone.  Most of what you see removed are people that write: "C#: How do I foo the bar?".  Prefixes like that don't belong, that's what tags are for.

Comment: The main tag is treated quite well, but sometimes the tag that has most questions is not neccesarily the tag that is most important for your questions. Especially in those cases including the (small) important tag can add value. The title should still be a proper sentence of course.

Comment: It should be noted that the "Hot Network Questions" that are immediately to the right of this answer have no tag information at all. Currently, I see a question in Arcade for "What Are The Mechanics For Attack-Move" and I have absolutely no idea what game it is for unless I click on the question. This negatively impacts my ability to determine if it is a question I have any interest in. The same is true for SO questions in that list.

Comment: @Ellesedil Lack of tags can be even abused. I've seen several times questions like "How to kill a cat without being punished?" which led to relatively innocent posts about games.