# Is there any way to flag a user's recent activity?

Tags: support, moderators

I've noticed a user repeatedly doing something incorrect, is there anyway to flag this user's recent activity for moderator attention?

Specifically, I've noticed a user erroneously editing question titles ([relevant meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253028/why-is-removing-tags-from-the-title-suggested-so-often)). I don't want to go flag every edit, and looking at their recent activity it's pretty clear they're doing this for every question they can.

How can I bring this to moderator attention?

Answer (score 1):

Just flag one of of the post where the edit went through as **in need of moderator intervention** and explain to the moderator what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Flag a post the user's recently edited.
Explain what's going on, and link to related meta posts in the explanation.