# A plethora of tags in titles

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, title

It's gotten to the point where, today, every question in my browser window started with a tag word in the title, and then added more. I struggle to even determine what the question is and, in many cases, there is nothing in the title but a row of tag words.

As we see from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076/512728) tags should not be in question titles.

**I propose that question titles having tags in titles get a warning because they are redundant, distract from what's being asked, and could even start appearing as ads for the tag and not a real question.**

I often edit the titles and remove the tag words to be more descriptive, but a warning would prevent many of these kinds of titles in the first place.

EDIT: I've also noticed that many of these same questions contain things like "Bootstrap gives error" where, if the *Bootstrap* tag was not allowed, they would be forced to give a more descriptive title.

EDIT: I'm talking about tag words without any markup: *word* (not things like *tag:word* or *[word]*) for tag <kbd>word</kbd>.

Examples:

- [Laravel : pivot table point to multiple tables* with tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437597/laravel-pivot-table-point-to-multiple-tables) <kbd>pivot</kbd> and <kbd>laravel-5.2</kbd>
- [Rails js.erb not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437247/rails-js-erb-not-working) with tags <kbd>rails</kbd>, <kbd>javascript</kbd>, <kbd>ruby-on-rails-4</kbd> and <kbd>erb</kbd>

(These are not the worst examples)

Comment: Could you plese name some examples?

Comment: Also, why is this a discussion?

Comment: @LutzHorn Go to SO. Look at the post titles. If you don't see any, wait a minute and refresh the page.

Comment: How would you define *"tags in titles"*, algorithmically? A match for any word or series of words in a title that matches any tag would be slow and likely very prone to false positives.

Comment: Yes, as you state. You can allow the question to pass through with the tags, to decrease the possibility of false positives, but at least warn the questioner that his title should not contain tags or, perhaps, should not contain the same words as in a tag.

Comment: This? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237156/213575

Comment: @Braiam No. The one in my edit.

Comment: I find it unbelievable that some people are trying to close this question cause they can't figure out what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Rob What do you mean by flag exactly? Are you talking about actual flags, or are you just suggesting a warning popup (like with regex)?

Comment: Here are two examples of tags in titles, both were within the top five questions when I opened SO this morning: [thing1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437597/laravel-pivot-table-point-to-multiple-tables) and [thing2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437247/rails-js-erb-not-working). These are not the worst examples

Answer (score 5):

I actually think that a properly executed filter would be beneficial.

(There is a similar Feature Request already at MSE: [Automatically remove the patterns "tag :" and "tag -" from titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138321))

I have made a query that reliably finds questions that use tags in the title:

```sql
Select top 3000
tags
, id as [Post Link]
from posts
where parentid is null
and lower(title) like substring(tags, 2, charindex('>', tags )-2)  + '[-:] %'
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/489694

While sometimes you can add tags into the title in a natural way (How do I write a query in *TSQL*?), my query only finds title like:

> android: google maps only a grey background as APK

There is no legitimate reason to allow titles like this as fas I am aware.

I'm not sure what the best solution is, but it might be a good idea to just silently strip them out like what is already done with excess punctuation.

To make everyone aware of the size of this issue, I ran a quick count query that would indicate that there are many questions with titles that follow one of several patterns:

- tag1: title words
- tag1- title words
- title words- tag1
- title words: tag1

## The query I ran returned 155,000 matches. There are likely many more out there.

There seem to be very few, if any false positives, but I am SURE I am missing a large quantity of questions. I am surely MISSING these titles in my query:

- The tag in the title is misspelled
- The tag in the title isn't the first tag in the tag field (the question may not even have the tag, because it was put in the title instead)
- The tag in the title uses spaces, not hyphens (as it would appear in the tag list)
- The title follows a similar pattern that my `LIKE` clauses will not match

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason for the question to be auto warned/flag just because has tag  in title as prefix, so if you have (and as your reputation you have) privileges just edit the title (if that bothers you so much) by removing it and move along, no need to raise flags here, it will increase a lot the flag queue for moderators when it is not necessary.

Comment: I have been doing this for weeks. At times, I feel it is all I do. That is why I suggest the warned/flag.

Comment: Note: I said nothing about the prefix. I am talking about anywhere in the title. This morning, with nothing to do for a bit, I've edited five or so questions within my browser window alone.

Comment: According to my calculations, there are AT LEAST **several hundred thousand** titles where the first tag is also a prefix or postfix to the title.